# Copying Tables Without Data in MySQL Retaining Auto Increment

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-schema, auto-increment

I have ran into trouble when copying my MySQL Tables to a new one, excluding the data, using the query:

`CREATE TABLE foo SELECT * FROM bar WHERE 1=0`.

The tables are copied, the structure and column names are correctly inserted. But there is a problem with the auto_increment fields and the primary key fields as they are not inserted as they were on the original table. (The fields are not PKs and AI anymore) I am using MySQL 5.5 and PMA 3.5.8.2

I hope someone can help me out.

Thank you SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably have to run 2 queries.

```
CREATE TABLE foo LIKE bar;
ALTER TABLE foo AUTO_INCREMENT = (SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT` FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DatabaseName' AND TABLE_NAME = 'bar');
```

You would have to replace DatabaseName with the name of your database.  This is untested, but I think it will give you what you are looking for.

So I tried testing the above query and the ALTER TABLE statement seems to fail due to the select.  There might be a better way, but the way that worked for me was to set the auto increment value to a variable and then prepare the statement and execute it.

For example you would go ahead and create your table first:

```
CREATE TABLE foo LIKE bar;
```

Then set your ALTER TABLE statement into a variable

```
SET @ai = CONCAT("ALTER TABLE foo AUTO_INCREMENT =", (SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'databasename' AND TABLE_NAME = 'bar'));
```

Finally, you would prepare and execute the statement.

```
PREPARE query FROM @ai;
EXECUTE query;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE query;
```

Comment: After running your SQL statement, I am faced with an error:
`end of input(-1,-1) expected token:( AS 
AUTO_INCREMENT(1,113) expected token:DROP CONSTRAINT TRIGGER `
Any ideas what am I doing wrong?
Here is my SQL statement:
CREATE TABLE foo SELECT * FROM bar WHERE 1=0;ALTER TABLE foo AUTO_INCREMENT = (SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT` FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'maknan_db1' AND TABLE_NAME = 'bar');`

Comment: Make sure to use CREATE TABLE foo LIKE bar; instead of your CREATE TABLE foo SELECT * FROM bar WHERE 1 = 0;

Comment: The way that you're creating your table is not copying the necessary information about the fields.  For example, which field has the auto_increment or is the primary key.

Comment: CREATE TABLE foo LIKE bar;


Actually did the trick! It copied everything except for the data from the original table. 
Thank you @Rylonian!

Answer (score 0):

Other than your columns, the table structure: indexes, primary keys, triggers, etc. are not copied by this kind of statement.  You either need to run a bunch of alter table statements to add your structure or you need to create the table with all the surrounding structure first, then load it with your select.